# How Partner Business Org is linked to Partner account?

Tags: managed-package, partner-communities

I have Partner Account and after signing of agreement I got the Partner Business Org.
So my question is how this PBO is linked to my Partner Account?

I've connected this org in Organizations tab in Partner account but there are no options for login etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the package to your partner business org (which usually has the LMA package installed, a necessary prerequisite).

Follow these instructions from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_publish_manage.htm.

> 1. Log in to the Partner Community.
> 2. On the Publishing page, click the
>    Packages tab.
> 3. Click Manage Licenses next to the package that you
>    want to register.
> 4. Click Register. Enter the login credentials for
>    the organization where the LMA is installed. Usually, the
>    organization is your partner business organization.
> 5. Select whether
>    your default license is Free Trial or Active.
> 6. If you selected a
>    free-trial license, enter the length of the trial, up to 90 days.
> 7. Enter the number of seats associated with your default license, or
>    select License is site-wide to offer the license to all users in the
>    installer’s organization.
> 8. Click Save.